# Set form field typed value to Javascript Variable and then using this value in another variable

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, dom, element

I'm a javascript noobie. I'm creating a form for visitors to  sign up to a webinar. I need to create a "unique code" or unique identifier for each visitor that submits the form.
For this I've created a hidden field called "Unique Code". This unique code is generated from a variable which concatenates a string, the email address value typed in the form and a webinar id that I assign from another variable. When I submit the form I just get the string and the webinar id concatenated by not the email address. The desired resulting value is something like this: GTW-visitor@emailaddress.com-12345. Here's my code:

```
  <form action="/destination/" method="post" name="GTW_Test_Form">
    <input type="hidden" name="gtwWebinarId" id="gtwWebinarId" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="uniqueCode" id="uniqueCode" value="">
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress"  required><br>
    <label for="name"><b>First Name</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" required><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Last Name</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register to webinar">
  </form>
```

And then, the javascript:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  var emailAddressInput = document.getElementById("emailAddress").value;
  var webinarId = "12345678";
  var uniqueCode = "GTW-" + emailAddressInput + "-" + webinarId;
  document.querySelector("#gtwWebinarId").value = webinarId;
  document.querySelector("#uniqueCode").value = uniqueCode;
</script>
```

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: It looks like your script doesn't run on an event listener; it doesn't run when the `submit` button is pressed and instead runs sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script runs even before the form fields have any value, you may have to write your script code inside a function which will be invoked by "onsubmit" event of the form.

```
<form onsubmit="foo(event)">

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    const foo = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailAddressInput = document.getElementById("emailAddress").value;
        var webinarId = "12345678";
        var uniqueCode = "GTW-" + emailAddressInput + "-" + webinarId;
        document.querySelector("#gtwWebinarId").value = webinarId;
        document.querySelector("#uniqueCode").value = uniqueCode;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `var emailAddressInput = document.querySelector("#emailAddress").value;`

Answer (score 0):

That actually worked! Thank you, Sai!